# Как изменить фон сайта с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Как изменить фон сайта нажимая на любое место(не с помощью кнопки) на JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.body.style.background = '#000'
})
```

Comment: А в body что то нужно прописывать?

Comment: В данном случае, document.body - это элемент у которого будет меняться фон. Подставить можно любой другой